# Why didn't Yukikaze vanish?

Tags: tokyo-ravens

In episode 20 of *Tokyo Ravens*...

> Natsume dies. At the beginning of episode 21, Hokuto (who is Natsume's familiar) appears to dissolve or vanish or something like that. However, in episodes 21 and 22, Touji is seen riding Yukikaze (her horse). Given that Yukikaze is also Natsume's familiar, why didn't Yukikaze vanish?

Comment: Actually, it's her father's familiar, she was just borrowing it.

Comment: I figured that might be the case, but I just rewatched all the currently-available episodes the other day and didn't catch that. Where is this explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see episode 9 between 9:54 - 10:03, Kurahashi Miyo says, "Take this. It is the Tsuchimikado family familiar, Yukikaze. Nastsume's father sent it".

This explain why Yukikaze did not vanish

> but Hokuto vanishes after death of Natsume.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFz6Y.gif) is the gif:

[image]